# Change the black background in flutter_zoom_drawer package?

Tags: flutter

I would like to change the black background that appears on this screenshot. I am using the [flutter_zoom_drawer](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_zoom_drawer/) package.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your color to the `menuBackgroundColor` property of the  ZoomDrawer class as:

```
ZoomDrawer(menuBackgroundColor: <your color>);
```

**Example**:

```
ZoomDrawer(menuBackgroundColor: Colors.red);
```